# "New" implementation with vtk and subclass

Tags: c++, subclass, instantiation, vtk

While simply trying to re-write one of the classes used in an example code of VTK (see [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/MoveCamera)), I decided to subclass `vtkInteractorStyle` in order to re-create a class very similar to `vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera`. Therefore I decide to copy/paste the implementation of `vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera` found [here](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Interaction/Style/vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera.cxx) and [here](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Interaction/Style/vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera.h) (github links to the code).

However, I noticed in this code that the `New()` method is not implemented in the `.cxx` file yet the example seems to work just fine. But when I try to re-create it with my own version of the trackballcamera I get a Linking error on the new method of my own subclass.

I therefore have two questions:

1. How come the implementation of the `New()` method is not in the `.cxx` file?
2. How come when I try to do the exact same thing (just copying/pasting and changing names) it does not work?

I am at a loss about these two 'issues'. Hope you can help me figure them out.

---

EDIT:
Here is the beginning of my header file:

```
#ifndef InteractorStyleTrackballCamera_h
#define InteractorStyleTrackballCamera_h

#include "vtkInteractionStyleModule.h" // For export macro
#include "vtkInteractorStyle.h"

class VTKINTERACTIONSTYLE_EXPORT InteractorStyleTrackballCamera : public vtkInteractorStyle
{
public:
  static InteractorStyleTrackballCamera *New();
  ....
```

And here is the beginning of my cpp file:

```
#include "InteractorStyleTrackballCamera.h"   
#include "vtkCamera.h"
#include "vtkCallbackCommand.h"
#include "vtkMath.h"
#include "vtkObjectFactory.h"
#include "vtkRenderWindow.h"
#include "vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h"
#include "vtkRenderer.h"

vtkStandardNewMacro(InteractorStyleTrackballCamera);

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
InteractorStyleTrackballCamera::InteractorStyleTrackballCamera()
{
  this->MotionFactor   = 10.0;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
InteractorStyleTrackballCamera::~InteractorStyleTrackballCamera()
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `VTKINTERACTIONSTYLE_EXPORT` in your header file unless you are building it into the vtkInteractionStyle library/module. You would have to have your own export macro for your library.

That macro effectively says "this class is exported when **building** the shared library, imported when **using** the shared library, and neither when library is static..."

Comment: Alright, that solved it. Thanks a lot. Upvote deserved for the extra explanations.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably missing the `vtkStandardNewMacro(<class_name>)` in the `.cxx` file. This defines the `New()` member function in a vast majority of VTK classes.

Comment: Worth an upvote for a point that I failed to notice first anyway (even though I had it here, it was not present on my tries)